# Wrong field editor resizing on column resize

Tags: resize, nstableview

The example project is at https://github.com/ivailon/test-008. The issue is that during resizing of the column width while editing cell, the field editor is not resizing correctly. In other words - once I start editing a cell, if I begin resizing the column, the field editor not only resizes incorrectly, but starts to act really strange - in most of the cases the text disappear or it's not possible to see what you are editing.
The example is simple enough .... just try it.
Is there anyone who can at least give an explanation why this is happening?

**EDIT:**
Problem solved. If someone is interested - the solution is in resizing the container too. I don't know why the container resizes only to smaller size ... maybe a bug in appkit ... maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you share what exactly you did to the container?

Comment: The solution I have is not ... good enough for me. But it may be good enough for you. Override setFrameSize of the field editor and resize the container by yourself.

Comment: I found my custom field editor has a superview of kind `_NSKeyboardFocusClipView` which seems to _clip_ the field editor; I dabbled with determining the field editor's `intrinsicContentSize`. Then I call `sizeToFit()` to adjust the frame. To affect the private superview, I override this method and set `self.superview?.frame = self.frame`. Works in there ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ;-) if it fits your needs - it's perfect for you. The other way is only 1 line though ...

Comment: In my case, I have a subclass of NSTextField and this did it: `[self currentEditor].superview.frame = [self.cell drawingRectForBounds:self.bounds];`